# Use like in join in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

```
public function get_rows_set_test( $table, $id_subjects )
{
    $this->db->select('id_sets','sets.sets_name');
    $this->db->from($table);
    $this->db->join('sets', 'sets.id LIKE CONCAT("%",questions.id_sets,"%")');  
    $this->db->where('id_subjects' , $id_subjects);
    $this->db->distinct();
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
        foreach( $query->result() as $row ) $rows[] = $row;
        return $rows;
    }
    else return '';
}
```

its gives this  error

```
Error Number: 1064
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`LIKE` CONCAT("%",questions.id_sets,"%") WHERE `id_subjects` = '13'' at line 3

SELECT DISTINCT `id_sets` FROM (`questions`) JOIN `sets` ON `sets`.`id` `LIKE` CONCAT("%",questions.id_sets,"%") WHERE `id_subjects` = '13'

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\modeltest\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
 error

Answer (score 0):

`$this->db->join('sets', 'sets.id LIKE CONCAT("%",questions.id_sets,"%")', false);`

Answer (score 0):

Please check below function with join between two tables:

```
public function get_rows_set_test( $table, $id_subjects )
{
    $this->db->select('id_sets','sets.sets_name');
    $this->db->from($table); 
    $this->db->join('sets','sets.id=questions.id_sets');
    $this->db->where('id_subjects' , $id_subjects);
    $this->db->distinct();
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
        foreach( $query->result() as $row ) $rows[] = $row;
        return $rows;
    }
    else return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the LIKE there, you are matching the two id I suppose, simple do the following

```
$this->db->join('sets','sets.id=questions.id_sets');
```

Comment: thanks ness. its like id is 47 and id_sets is 0,47,0 . so i needed like to fetch the id .how to do it , ?

Comment: can you post your table structures? what data type is questions.id_sets?

Answer (score -2):

You could write it as a stored procedure on the database side then use:

```
   `$query = $this->db->query("call stored_procedure()");'
```

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/call_function.html